# Extended controller URL and configuration

Tags: extensions, url, controllers, ajax

I'm developing an ajax request handling extension of the default cart controller.  How do I find out the correct URL to use in order to send information back to the server?

the controller (CartController.php) class definition is:

```
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';
class CompanyName_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController{
    function couponPostAction(){
    }
}
```

the config.xml will look something like:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
    <checkout>
        <args>
            <modules>
                <companyname_checkout before="Mage_Checkout">Companyname_checkout</companyname_checkout>
            </modules>
        </args>
    </checkout>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

Assuming the above is correctly configured... what will be the resultant URL I will use to reach this controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL to use will just be the default URL as you are simply telling Magento to load your controller first. Therefore, for the shown action the url is simply `checkout/cart/couponPost`.